# Measurement invariance testing with ordinal data using lavaan: what is really happening under the hood?

Tags: factor-analysis, ordinal-data, lavaan, invariance

I've been trying to wrap my head around measurement invariance testing with ordinal data in R version 4.2.2 using lavaan 0.6-13. It all seemed rather straight-forward in theory, but I believe I am becoming more confused with each day I spend with this code. I am working with a 20-item depression scale (response options 0,1,2,3), the invariance of which I want to assess with two very unequally sized groups (n=1390 and n=260).

I have read about different approaches to measurement invariance testing with ordinal data, and two examples using R have been this https://giacomomason.com/post/measurement-invariance-with-categorical-items/ and https://towardsdatascience.com/testing-for-measurement-invariance-in-r-b44cace10148.

The first link refers to a paper by Hu & Estabrook (2016) https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27402166/, which frankly for the most part flies over my head, but I gather that specifying any type of factor model using ordinal data imposes constraints, which makes the nested invariance testing sequence (used in the second link) problematic since your configural model may be equivalent to a later, supposedly more strict model.

So far in lavaan I have used the "ordered=TRUE" for all my analyses. This, as explained in a lavaan tutorial (https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html), "will automatically switch to the WLSMV estimator: it will use diagonally weighted least squares (DWLS) to estimate the model parameters, but it will use the full weight matrix to compute robust standard errors, and a mean- and variance-adjusted test stastistic."

1. With the above information about lavaan's ordered function, I assumed that ordered=TRUE would be equal to setting the estimator to "WLSMV". This is not the case, as using ordered=TRUE sets all intercepts to 0 and scales y*=1, while estimator="WLSMV" does not. It also turns out that some analyses run fine and give interpretable summary statistics with ordered=TRUE, whereas they fail to run with estimator="WLSMV" with the warning: *Warning message:
   In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
   lavaan WARNING:
   The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
   does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
   (= 5.848539e-15) is close to zero. This may be a symptom that the
   model is not identified.*

My first question is: what does ordered=TRUE exactly do, and should I use that or try to get the estimator="WLSMV" to work? It does not appear to make sense to use ordered=TRUE when testing for invariance for intercepts, if the procedure sets all intercepts to zero.

2. I have seen people recommend using theta parameterization with WLSMV for invariance testing (e.g. the first link by Giacomo Mason, some published papers in the depression literature). When doing this in R, is it necessary to first transform the data as suggested in the first link, or will parameterization="theta" transform the data itself? Using non-transformed data, a combination of estimator="WLSMV" and parameterization="theta" gives identical results to estimator="WLSMV", so I suppose the transformation is needed?
3. If the above transformation is necessary, is there something I could do to fix the following error: *In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length*
   Which gets repeated over 20 times? I suspect it has something to do with one of the items of the scale, which did not receive any answers of '3' so I collapsed the zero answers to 2. Here is the code for the four-factor model following the method advocated by Giacomo Mason. I've went over the code to see if there is something misspecified in the model but I am not sure since mine has more factors than the example code provided in the blog post.

```
cesd20_conf.model <- 'F1 =~ Crying + Sad + Depressed + Lonely + Blues + Fearful + Bothered + Sleep
F2 =~ Concentrating + Going + Effort + Appetite + Talk
F3 =~ Enjoyed + Happy + Hopeful + Good + Failure
F4 =~ Dislike.c + Unfriendly
Crying | t1 + t2 + t3
Sad | t1 + t2 + t3
Depressed | t1 + t2 + t3
Lonely | t1 + t2 + t3
Blues | t1 + t2 + t3
Fearful | t1 + t2 + t3
Bothered | t1 + t2 + t3
Sleep | t1 + t2 + t3
Concentrating | t1 + t2 + t3
Going | t1 + t2 + t3
Effort | t1 + t2 + t3
Appetite | t1 + t2 + t3
Talk | t1 + t2 + t3
Enjoyed | t1 + t2 + t3
Happy | t1 + t2 + t3
Hopeful | t1 + t2 + t3
Good | t1 + t2 + t3
Failure | t1 + t2 + t3
Dislike.c | t1 + t2
Unfriendly | t1 + t2 + t3
Crying ~~ c(1, 1)*Crying
Sad ~~ c(1, 1)*Sad
Depressed ~~ c(1, 1)*Depressed
Lonely ~~ c(1, 1)*Lonely
Blues ~~ c(1, 1)*Blues
Fearful ~~ c(1, 1)*Fearful
Bothered ~~ c(1, 1)*Bothered
Sleep ~~ c(1, 1)*Sleep
Concentrating ~~ c(1, 1)*Concentrating
Going ~~ c(1, 1)*Going
Effort ~~ c(1, 1)*Effort
Appetite ~~ c(1, 1)*Appetite
Talk ~~ c(1, 1)*Talk
Enjoyed ~~ c(1, 1)*Enjoyed
Happy ~~ c(1, 1)*Happy
Hopeful ~~ c(1, 1)*Hopeful
Good ~~ c(1, 1)*Good
Failure ~~ c(1, 1)*Failure
Dislike.c ~~ c(1, 1)*Dislike.c
Unfriendly ~~ c(1, 1)*Unfriendly
Crying ~ c(0, 0)*1
Sad ~ c(0, 0)*1
Depressed ~ c(0, 0)*1
Lonely ~ c(0, 0)*1
Blues ~ c(0, 0)*1
Fearful ~ c(0, 0)*1
Bothered ~ c(0, 0)*1
Sleep ~ c(0, 0)*1
Concentrating ~ c(0, 0)*1
Going ~ c(0, 0)*1
Effort ~ c(0, 0)*1
Appetite ~ c(0, 0)*1
Talk ~ c(0, 0)*1
Enjoyed ~ c(0, 0)*1
Happy ~ c(0, 0)*1
Hopeful ~ c(0, 0)*1
Good ~ c(0, 0)*1
Failure ~ c(0, 0)*1
Dislike.c ~ c(0, 0)*1
Unfriendly ~ c(0, 0)*1
F1 ~~ c(1,1)*F1
F2 ~~ c(1,1)*F2
F3 ~~ c(1,1)*F3
F4 ~~ c(1,1)*F4
F1 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F2 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F3 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F4 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F1 ~~ NA*F2
F1 ~~ NA*F3
F1 ~~ NA*F4
F2 ~~ NA*F3
F2 ~~ NA*F4
F3 ~~ NA*F4'

c20_fit1 <- lavaan(cesd20_conf.model, 
                   data = df3, group = "cog",
                   parameterization="theta", estimator="wlsmv",
                   auto.fix.first = FALSE)
```

With a subset of the scale (8 items, without the Dislike.c item) I could do the analysis and proceed from configural, threshold, threshold & loadings and threshold, loadings & intercepts constrained and these four models were almost indistinguishable (different df's and chi square statistics though). These analyses were ran with the code provided by Giacomo Mason with my own variables substituted in. What made me doubt these results was that the fit did not appreciably get worse, in fact in some cases it got even better, so I was wondering if I was doing much at all in terms of adding constraints. The warning also makes me wary of the logic in these analyses. Here is the code for the four models:

```
cesd8_conf.model <- 'F1 =~ Depressed + Sad + Lonely + Sleep
F2 =~ Enjoyed + Happy
F3 =~ Effort + Going
Depressed | t1 + t2 + t3
Sad | t1 + t2 + t3
Lonely | t1 + t2 + t3
Sleep | t1 + t2 + t3
Enjoyed | t1 + t2 + t3
Happy | t1 + t2 + t3
Effort | t1 + t2 + t3
Going | t1 + t2 + t3
Sad ~~ c(1, 1)*Sad
Depressed ~~ c(1, 1)*Depressed
Lonely ~~ c(1, 1)*Lonely
Sleep ~~ c(1, 1)*Sleep
Going ~~ c(1, 1)*Going
Effort ~~ c(1, 1)*Effor
Enjoyed ~~ c(1, 1)*Enjoyed
Happy ~~ c(1, 1)*Happy
F1 ~~ c(1,1)*F1
F2 ~~ c(1,1)*F2
F3 ~~ c(1,1)*F3
F1 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F2 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F3 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F1 ~~ NA*F2
F1 ~~ NA*F3
F2 ~~ NA*F3'

c8_fit1 <- lavaan(cesd8_conf.model, 
                   data = df3, group = "cog",
                   parameterization="theta", estimator="wlsmv",
                   auto.fix.first = FALSE) #
summary(c8_fit1, fit.measures = TRUE)

#Threshold invariance#
c8_tres <- 'F1 =~ Depressed + Sad + Lonely + Sleep
F2 =~ Enjoyed + Happy
F3 =~ Effort + Going
Depressed | c(t1_1, t1_1)*t1 + c(t2_1, t2_1)*t2 + c(t3_1, t3_1)*t3
      Sad | c(t1_2, t1_2)*t1 + c(t2_2, t2_2)*t2 + c(t3_2, t3_2)*t3
   Lonely | c(t1_3, t1_3)*t1 + c(t2_3, t2_3)*t2 + c(t3_3, t3_3)*t3
    Sleep | c(t1_4, t1_4)*t1 + c(t2_4, t2_4)*t2 + c(t3_4, t3_4)*t3 
  Enjoyed | c(t1_5, t1_5)*t1 + c(t2_5, t2_5)*t2 + c(t3_5, t3_5)*t3 
    Happy | c(t1_6, t1_6)*t1 + c(t2_6, t2_6)*t2 + c(t3_6, t3_6)*t3 
   Effort | c(t1_7, t1_7)*t1 + c(t2_7, t2_7)*t2 + c(t3_7, t3_7)*t3 
    Going | c(t1_8, t1_8)*t1 + c(t2_8, t2_8)*t2 + c(t3_8, t3_8)*t3 

Depressed ~~ c(1, NA)*Depressed
Sad ~~ c(1, NA)*Sad
Lonely ~~ c(1, NA)*Lonely
Sleep ~~ c(1, NA)*Sleep
Enjoyed ~~ c(1, NA)*Enjoyed
Happy ~~ c(1, NA)*Happy
Effort ~~ c(1, NA)*Effort
Going ~~ c(1, NA)*Going
Depressed  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Sad  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Lonely  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Sleep  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Enjoyed  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Happy  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Effort  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Going  ~ c(0, NA)*1

F1 ~~ c(1,1)*F1
F2 ~~ c(1,1)*F2
F3 ~~ c(1,1)*F3
F1 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F2 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F3 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F1 ~~ NA*F2
F1 ~~ NA*F3
F2 ~~ NA*F3'

c8_fit2 <- lavaan(c8_tres, 
                  data = df3, group = "cog",
                  parameterization="theta", estimator="wlsmv",
                  auto.fix.first = FALSE)
summary(c8_fit2, fit.measures = TRUE)

#Thresholds and loadings
c8_trelo <- 'F1 =~ c(l1, l1)*Depressed + c(l2, l2)*Sad + c(l3, l3)*Lonely + c(l4, l4)*Sleep
F2 =~ c(l5, l5)*Enjoyed + c(l6, l6)*Happy
F3 =~ c(l7, l7)*Effort + c(l8, l8)*Going
Depressed | c(t1_1, t1_1)*t1 + c(t2_1, t2_1)*t2 + c(t3_1, t3_1)*t3
      Sad | c(t1_2, t1_2)*t1 + c(t2_2, t2_2)*t2 + c(t3_2, t3_2)*t3
   Lonely | c(t1_3, t1_3)*t1 + c(t2_3, t2_3)*t2 + c(t3_3, t3_3)*t3
    Sleep | c(t1_4, t1_4)*t1 + c(t2_4, t2_4)*t2 + c(t3_4, t3_4)*t3 
  Enjoyed | c(t1_5, t1_5)*t1 + c(t2_5, t2_5)*t2 + c(t3_5, t3_5)*t3 
    Happy | c(t1_6, t1_6)*t1 + c(t2_6, t2_6)*t2 + c(t3_6, t3_6)*t3 
   Effort | c(t1_7, t1_7)*t1 + c(t2_7, t2_7)*t2 + c(t3_7, t3_7)*t3 
    Going | c(t1_8, t1_8)*t1 + c(t2_8, t2_8)*t2 + c(t3_8, t3_8)*t3 

Depressed ~~ c(1, NA)*Depressed
Sad ~~ c(1, NA)*Sad
Lonely ~~ c(1, NA)*Lonely
Sleep ~~ c(1, NA)*Sleep
Enjoyed ~~ c(1, NA)*Enjoyed
Happy ~~ c(1, NA)*Happy
Effort ~~ c(1, NA)*Effort
Going ~~ c(1, NA)*Going
Depressed  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Sad  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Lonely  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Sleep  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Enjoyed  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Happy  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Effort  ~ c(0, NA)*1
Going  ~ c(0, NA)*1

F1 ~~ c(1,1)*F1
F2 ~~ c(1,1)*F2
F3 ~~ c(1,1)*F3
F1 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F2 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F3 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F1 ~~ NA*F2
F1 ~~ NA*F3
F2 ~~ NA*F3'

c8_fit3 <- lavaan(c8_trelo, 
                    data = df3, group = "cog",
                    parameterization="theta", estimator="wlsmv",
                    auto.fix.first = FALSE)
summary(c8_fit3, fit.measures = TRUE)

#Thresholds, loadings, intercepts
c8_treloin <- 'F1 =~ c(l1, l1)*Depressed + c(l2, l2)*Sad + c(l3, l3)*Lonely + c(l4, l4)*Sleep
F2 =~ c(l5, l5)*Enjoyed + c(l6, l6)*Happy
F3 =~ c(l7, l7)*Effort + c(l8, l8)*Going
Depressed | c(t1_1, t1_1)*t1 + c(t2_1, t2_1)*t2 + c(t3_1, t3_1)*t3
      Sad | c(t1_2, t1_2)*t1 + c(t2_2, t2_2)*t2 + c(t3_2, t3_2)*t3
   Lonely | c(t1_3, t1_3)*t1 + c(t2_3, t2_3)*t2 + c(t3_3, t3_3)*t3
    Sleep | c(t1_4, t1_4)*t1 + c(t2_4, t2_4)*t2 + c(t3_4, t3_4)*t3 
  Enjoyed | c(t1_5, t1_5)*t1 + c(t2_5, t2_5)*t2 + c(t3_5, t3_5)*t3 
    Happy | c(t1_6, t1_6)*t1 + c(t2_6, t2_6)*t2 + c(t3_6, t3_6)*t3 
   Effort | c(t1_7, t1_7)*t1 + c(t2_7, t2_7)*t2 + c(t3_7, t3_7)*t3 
    Going | c(t1_8, t1_8)*t1 + c(t2_8, t2_8)*t2 + c(t3_8, t3_8)*t3 

Depressed ~~ c(1, NA)*Depressed
Sad ~~ c(1, NA)*Sad
Lonely ~~ c(1, NA)*Lonely
Sleep ~~ c(1, NA)*Sleep
Enjoyed ~~ c(1, NA)*Enjoyed
Happy ~~ c(1, NA)*Happy
Effort ~~ c(1, NA)*Effort
Going ~~ c(1, NA)*Going
Depressed  ~ c(0, 0)*1
      Sad  ~ c(0, 0)*1
   Lonely  ~ c(0, 0)*1
    Sleep  ~ c(0, 0)*1
  Enjoyed  ~ c(0, 0)*1
    Happy  ~ c(0, 0)*1
   Effort  ~ c(0, 0)*1
    Going  ~ c(0, 0)*1

F1 ~~ c(1,NA)*F1
F2 ~~ c(1,NA)*F2
F3 ~~ c(1,NA)*F3
F1 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F2 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F3 ~ c(0, 0)*1
F1 ~~ NA*F2
F1 ~~ NA*F3
F2 ~~ NA*F3'

c8_fit4 <- lavaan(c8_treloin, 
                  data = df3, group = "cog",
                  parameterization="theta", estimator="wlsmv",
                  auto.fix.first = FALSE)
summary(c8_fit4, fit.measures = TRUE)
Warning message:
In lavTestLRT(c8_fit1, c8_fit2, c8_fit3, c8_fit4) : lavaan WARNING:
    Some restricted models fit better than less restricted models;
    either these models are not nested, or the less restricted model
    failed to reach a global optimum. Smallest difference =
    -10.9216882838775
```

So I guess tl;dr version is that should I use ordinal=TRUE or estimator="WLSMV", when should I use theta parameterization, and what do the answers to the aforementioned two questions mean for the constraints I have already imposed on the identified model? If I have an item with less response options used (e.g. 0-2) than the others (e.g. 0-3), am I screwed?

Comment: I designed the `measEq.syntax()` function in the `semTools` package to ease the process of applying Wu & Estabrook's (2016) recommendations.  The help-page examples use categorical data, so you can see how (relatively) easy it is to simply choose your identification method(s) and let the function write the lavaan `model.syntax` for you.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, that function is a life-saver! Also appreciate the fact that it spells out for the more uninitiated of us that what exactly is being held constant.  I followed the procedure laid out in the examples, so I did configural -> thresholds -> threshold, loadings -> thresholds, loadings, intercepts. Any idea on what, if anything, it means that my scalar invariance models had the best fit out of all four tested? (The same observation was made here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33269612/, but I am not sure the procedure is comparable).

Comment: It is more constrained, so can't fit better, unless you are referring to some parsimony adjustment.  e.g., chi-squared might increase less than its *df*